# Recommended design for OTP/2FA support in OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm trying to add OTP/2FA support into OAuth2, but after much reading through the [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749), it's still not clear how OTP/2FA could be cleanly added without violating the specification.

Although OTP/2FA entry can be added into the `authorize` dialog flow, there is no provision for adding it into `token`. For example, `public` client apps with `Resource owner password-based` privileges may want to provide the token directly when requesting a new `access_token`, rather than having to embed a HTML dialog box.

Therefore my questions are;

- Does the RFC allow for custom `grant_type`? Should this be used to provide 2FA/OTP functionality?
- Does the RFC allow for additional attributes on an existing `grant_type`? For example, `grant_type=token&otp_code=1234` (RFC does not make it clear if additional attributes are allowed on `grant_type`'s within the specification)
- Should OTP functionality be placed into headers? This is the approach that Github [used](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/), but it feels really ugly/hacky.
- Are there any other approaches that I have overlooked?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RFC allows for an extension (custom) grant, see section https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-8.3. That grant could define additional attributes.

OAuth 2.0 does not define how the Resource Owner authenticates to the Authorization Server, with the exception of the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant. Your proposal could be designed as an extended variant of that grant.

Comment: Upon reviewing the RFC, it would seem that `client_credentials` grant does not specify whether additional attributes can be provided in the POST data, and gives an example of providing an `Authorization` header. Could I add attributes into the POST data and JSON response of `client_credentials` grant, without fear of violating the RFC?

Comment: The `client_credentials` grant would apply only if the client gets a token on its own merits, independent of the user. That's not the case here as I understand. You'll need a flow that is similar to Resource Owner Password Credentials grant, but with an extra OTP included in the authentication request.

Comment: That makes sense now. Am I correct in saying that, in this particular situation, the best route forward would be to use an extension (custom) grant?

Comment: yes, that's the way forward; modifying an existing grant would violate the spec

Comment: Answer accepted, thank you for taking time to review/answer

Comment: btw: if you use the OTP as a single factor you may just use the existing Resource Owner Password Credentials grant and supply the OTP as the password in there

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on something similar. I've got an endpoint at which you can request certain metadata for a user such as whether or not 2fa / mfa / otp is turned on and the salt (and iterations and algorithm) for Proof of Secret / Secure Remote Password.

If you go that route you can simply extend the grant types with an mfa or totp field (that's what I'm doing). You could also create a custom grant type as mentioned above (perhaps more proper).

Another solution is to check for MFA / 2FA / OTP during the authorization dialog step.

If I were done with my OAuth2 implementation I'd link you to that code too, but here are some libraries for an Authenticator:

- [Browser Authenticator](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/browser-authenticator.js) has the components you need to generate and verify a key and token in the browser: https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/browser-authenticator.js
- [Node Authenticator](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/node-authenticator.js) has the complementary server-side code: https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/node-authenticator.js

You would still need to provide your own database storage mechanism and link it in to your OAuth implementation or you could make a very simple one and run it as a microservice.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Hanz Z.: you can design your own grant type to consume OTP.
But OTP can also be used for client authentication (confidential clients as you have to store credentials).

For example, we could imagine an header in the token request (`X-OAuth2-OTP` = 01234567). Client authentification will fail if the client activated OTP but no header is set.

Comment: That makes sense, although pushing it into headers does seem a bit dirty. And how about situations where you want to inform the user about the OTP mechanism triggered? For example, an OTP was sent to the users cell phone (partially redacted), and we want to include this in the response. It seems a lot simpler to include this information inside a JSON blob, rather than encoding it into an `X-OAuth2-OTP` header.

Answer (score 0):

Based on specifc SCOPE (Ex. OTP) you can mark bearer(access_token) as ""verified_otp = false"" on the backend, then after authorization server received valid otp for that session mark your bearer(access_token) as ""verified_otk = true"". For your resource server, check verified_otk field befores authorize calls that depends this verification.