# Recommended flow for otp and password based login

Tags: oauth-2.0

After spending hours on research for finding right approach I am asking this question. I am new to oAuth and openid so request you to pardon my knowledge gaps.

We use open Id with oAuth 2 (implicit flow) currently in our organisation. We have a separate resource server and authorisation server. We use google based single sign in and email, password for login.

We are planning to move to have sms otp based login, gmail login and email password. Meaning keep these 3 alternatives. I am really not sure which is the best design for this use case. We have web application and trusted clients but no app and use .net for our authentication.

The following link on stack overflow gives some idea but I am not sure how to support my hybrid use cases in secure manner.

[Recommended design for OTP/2FA support in OAuth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834078/recommended-design-for-otp-2fa-support-in-oauth2)

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the question is quite old but I thought of adding an answer to help others. I ended up implementing a solution that has worked so far very well. We used the resource owner's flow for top based login. The top became the password and the mobile number became username. Upon successful validation, the OTP expires and the token is returned which can be used to call other APIs. Google login is implicit oauth2 flow.